# Ruby on Rails The kept

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
od_practice.partnerships.kept.first&.omd_practice&.id
```

I have seen people use the word `kept.first` to pull data from database in ruby on rail . What does these words mean ? i have tried to do some research and i seem not find any solution. Can someone explain me please ?

Comment: `kept` likely comes from `Discard::Model` (gem `discard`). Look it up.

Comment: I assume you don't actually have problems with `first`. If you do, then reading a rails book or tutorial should help. I like https://www.railstutorial.org/. For a quick fix, read this guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is called a *message send* in Ruby. In some other languages, it might be called a *method call*.

It is sending the message `kept` with no arguments to the object that was the result of evaluating the beginning of the message chain. This message send will in turn result in an object being returned, and it is then sending the message `first` to that object, again with no arguments.